# Underrealm Lich and Divination

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Underrealm Lich](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=452961)'s static ability reads:

> If you would draw a card, instead look at the top three cards of your library, then put one into your hand and the rest into your graveyard.

[Divination](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=447187) reads:

> Draw two cards.

**Which of the following statements is correct?**

- **A)** Do I look at the top three cards of my library, then put one into my hand and the rest into my graveyard, and do the same again?
- **B)** Or do I look at the top six cards of my library, then put two into my hand and the rest into my graveyard?

I guess option A is true, but where is this clarified in the rules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's option A). From the [Comprehensive Rules](http://media.wizards.com/2018/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020181005.txt):

> 120.2. Cards may only be drawn one at a time. If a player is instructed to draw multiple cards, that player performs that many individual card draws.

Each individual card draw gets replaced by "instead look at the top three cards of your library, then put one into your hand and the rest into your graveyard."

In fact, this very situation is mentioned in the Rulings below the card on Gatherer:

> If an effect instructs you to draw multiple cards, each draw is performed—and replaced by Underrealm Lich’s ability—one at a time. This means that if you’re drawing two cards, you’ll look at the top three cards of your library, put one into your hand, put the other two into your graveyard, and then repeat the process with the next three cards in your library.

Comment: "In fact, this very situation is mentioned in the Rulings below the card on Gatherer:"  - very humiliating. Thank you for your answer anyway.